# No leo datos de dos puertos serie. en C++

Tags: c++

**#Tengo dos dispositivos conectados a puertos COM.#**
*Pretendo leer datos de ambos, según me interese y enviarles ordenes.
El problema es que solo obtengo datos del dispositivo que primero despierta y envía su identificación y así  queda apuntando el 'hComm ' en el RX.

Llevo varios días y no veo como darle solución.
Adjunto un  trozo del programa reducido que utilizo para pruebas ,
es bastante "espartano"  *

Publico el código de la parte RX en el cpp.
Incluso tapando en el main del for de pruebas:
//int cuant2 = PortArd_2.Rx();
sigo teniendo en el lpBuffer de entrada datos del segundo puerto.
Me tiene totalmente despistado, he de reconocer que solo había trabajado con un puerto COM, nunca con más de uno a la vez.
Y además los COM no son mi fuerte.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "PortCom.h"
char BufferSal[100]{};
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!\n";
    PortCom PortArd_1;
    PortCom PortArd_2;

    PortArd_1.ini('5', 115000);
    PortArd_2.ini('6', 115000);


    for (int b = 0; b < 40; b++) {   // BREAK  TEST
        
        int cuant1 = PortArd_1.Rx();
        int cuant2 = PortArd_2.Rx();
        printf ( "\nPort ARD_1 Read: %d :: Port ARD_2 Read: %d\n", cuant1, cuant2);
    }
}
---------------------------

HANDLE hComm;
////////////////////////////
//TROZO de PortCom.cpp
{
/////////////////////// 

bool PortCom::ini(char nuport, int baud){
/
/
    hComm = CreateFileA(val,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,                                
        NULL,                       
        OPEN_EXISTING,                  
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,          
        NULL);                          

}
//-------------------------

int PortCom::Rx()
{
    bool Status;
    char lpBuffer[300];
    extern char BufferSal[];
    DWORD dNoOFBytesttoRead = 300;
    DWORD dNoOFBytesRead = 0;
    Status = ReadFile(hComm,lpBuffer,dNoOFBytesttoRead,&dNoOFBytesRead,NULL);
    if (Status) {
        &dNoOFBytesRead,
            printf ( "\n READ FILE: %d \n", dNoOFBytesRead);
    }
    if (dNoOFBytesRead > 0) {
        for (int b = 0; b < dNoOFBytesRead; b++)
        {
            BufferSal[b] = lpBuffer[b];
        }
    }
    bool resu = PurgeComm(hComm, PURGE_RXCLEAR);
    return dNoOFBytesRead;
}
```

Comment: Claro que tienes datos *repetidos* si la función siempre hace referencia a la variable global `bufferSal`. Mejor utiliza buffers separados y pásalos como parámetros.

Comment: Si entendí tu comentario, se trataría de utilizar bufferSal_1 y bufferSal_2.

Comment: @Mateo Creo que el problema está con lpBuffer y si Sal_1 y2 copian de lpBuffer y esta no varia. Lo probaré

Comment: No veo `bufferSal_1` ni `bufferSal_2`. Solo existe una variable global llamada `bufferSal` que comparten todas las instancias. En mí opinión está mal, cada instancia debería trabajar con su propia memoria. Por cierto, con `PurgeComm` es posible que pierdas datos.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado .
El problema está en donde se define el HANDLE hComm;
Debe definirse en el fichero .h
Gracias.